# Вывод мусора в динамически выделенной строке

Tags: c, строки, динамические-структуры

Имеется динамическая структура данных в функции PrintTabl я сделал так что бы значение 3 полей моей структуры записать в одну строку(имя,фамилия и отчество в 3 разных переменных)

```
void PrintTabl(LEL* p)
{
  int len = 40;// длинна строки + 1 элемент признака конца строки


    char *str = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));

      strcat(str,p->inform.sname);
      strcat(str," ");
      strcat(str,p->inform.fname);
      strcat(str," ");
      strcat(str,p->inform.tname);
      strcat(str," ");

      printf("%-39s",str);
      printf("%-16s",p->inform.pnumber);
      printf("%-31s",p->inform.address);
      printf("%-11s",p->inform.family);
      printf("%-8s",p->inform.sallary);
      printf("\n");

      free(str);


  printf("\n");

}
```

После запуска программы мы заполняем данными нашу очередь и при вызове функции PrintTabl(а конкретнее при работе строки printf("%-39s",str); перед информацией выводятся 3 мусорных символа(если можно их так назвать) и после free(ptr) они все равно остаються[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы упустили особенность работы функции `strcat`. Она выполняет 2 вещи: 1) Ищет позицию конца первой строки (т.е. символа `0`) 2) Начиная с найденной позиции добавляет вторую строку. А после `malloc`  ваша первая строка ещё не является действительно строкой, т.е. символ `0` в ней может напрочь отсутствовать и `strcat` при его поиске может выйти далеко за пределы выделенной памяти и вызвать в итоге ошибку повреждения памяти, при попытке дописать туда вторую строку. Так что, с тремя мусорными символами в начале строки, вам ещё сильно повезло.

Comment: man *asprintf()*, гораздо удобнее, чем ваше сочинение.

Comment: @0andriy Функция, безусловно, полезная, но она не входит в стандарт и, соответственно, доступна не на всех платформах.

Comment: @zed её можно довольно легко имплементировать, используя *snprintf()* и *malloc()*. И получится всё равно красивее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char *str = (char*)malloc(len*sizeof(char));
```

В этот момент в этом месте в памяти - мусор...

```
strcat(str,p->inform.sname);
```

А вы к нему **добавляете**.

Или после выделения памяти сделайте инициализацию

```
str[0] = 0;
```

или первый `strcat` замените на `strcpy`.